# error: no suitable method found for showInputDialog(<null>,String,int,<null>,String[],String)

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a fraction calculator in java, I'm using the drop box int Joptionpane to display the arithmetic operations, but I keep getting an error whenever I compile the code.

```
String [] sChoice = {"+","-","*","/"};
            JComboBox<String> jcb = new
            JComboBox<>(sChoice);
            String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Choise your opperator",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null,sChoice,sChoice[0]);
```

Heres the full error I'm getting.

.java:47: error: no suitable method found for showInputDialog(,String,int,,String[],String)
                        String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Choise your opperator",
                                                          ^
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Object,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon,Object[],Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Check [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)). You forgot the title parameter.

Comment: Also, the method call is not closed. Add ); to the end of line 47.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please add the formatted stack trace.

Number of arguments might be the issue.

Try changling like this, for example

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " " , "txt");
```

Comment: beautifying the exception stack trace so that it is easy to read.

Comment: depends on the number of arguments.

for example,

JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Anyone there?");
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Anyone there?", 42);

Please refer: https://www.mkyong.com/swing/java-swing-joptionpane-showinputdialog-example/